# Spring jpa entity manager getResultList returning data from multiple tables to fit in to non model class

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am doing a spring jpa project. i have a query that gets data from **5 Tables**.

i have used the entity manager.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(myQuery);
    query.setParameter("systemUserId", userid);
    query.setParameter("firstResult", firstResult);
    query.setParameter("lastResult", lastResult);

   query.getResultList();
```

now   query.getResultList() is returning the list of objects. so i need to write a mapper to fit data for non model class.

is there a way i can directly fit the query result to a non model class ?

Comment: How does the result look like that you get from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
   List<Object[]> data = query.list();
    List<SomeDTO> list = new ArrayList<SomeDTO>();
    for (Object[] o : data) {
        SomeDTO r = new SomeDTO();

        String articleName = (String) o[0];
        r.setArticleName((kirmark.replace("_", " ") + " - " + articleName.replace("_", " ")));
        r.setArticleType((String) o[1]);
        r.setArticleZone((BigDecimal) o[2]);
        r.setArticleQuantity((BigDecimal) o[3]);
        r.setArticlePrice((BigDecimal) o[4]);
        list.add(r);
        }
        return list;
```

Comment: thanks Candy. we have anything like,  in repository directly query result will be mapped to the Model. same here can we map here query result to the non model class.